# Parsing array of objects into a function

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java and have had this problem the whole day.
I am trying to implement a FCFS scheduler, and i am stuck where the user is asked to enter the number of processes in the form of a string.

Also declared an array of type process and made a function which cut the strings into integers representing burst time and arrival time.

so far so good but when i try to print the values something goes wrong

```
public class Process {

private static int BT;
private static int AT;


Process(){
    AT=0;
    BT=0;
}
Process(int burst, int arrival){
    BT=burst;
    AT=arrival;
}
//GETS and SETS
public static void setBT(int burst){
    BT=burst;
}
public int getBT(){

    return BT;
}
public static void setAT(int arrival){
    AT=arrival;
}
public int getAT(){

    return AT;
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Process pArray[]=new Process[10];

    System.out.println("Choose the Scheduler \n 1-FCFS");
    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
    int schedulerType = input.nextInt();

    switch(schedulerType){
    case 1:
        System.out.println("You have choosen FCFS Scheduler");
        System.out.println("Now enter the Process each seperated by a semicolon where the first number is the Burst time, and the second is the Arrival time separated by a comma");
        System.out.println("EX: 1,2;3,4;");

        stringcutter( pArray );

        System.out.println(pArray[0].getBT());
        System.out.println(pArray[0].getAT());


        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("You have entered a wrong scheduler Type");
    }




public static void stringcutter(Process[] processArray){
    String pString="1,2;3,4;";

    String[] array=pString.split(";");
    int processesNumber=array.length;

    for(int i=0;i<processesNumber;i++){
        String[] oneProcess =array[i].split(",");
        int burstTime = Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[0]);
        int arrivalTime = Integer.parseInt(oneProcess[1]);

        processArray[i] =new Process(burstTime,arrivalTime);

    }
}
```

}

I expected the output to be numbers 1 and 2, instead i am getting 3 and 4

also ran the debugger but with no luck of finding the problem.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz problem was that I used more than one Static variable
Thansk for your help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `static` modifier for the variable `AT` and `BT`. There can be only one instance of static variables. So use nonstatic fields instead of static variables.

```
private int BT;
private int AT;
```